# Text inside a hollowed box

Tags: python, format

I wrote some code that makes a hollowed box of any size:

```
_char = input('Please enter a character: ')
width = int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
height = int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
for row in range(width):
    for col in range(height):
         print( _char if row in(0,width-1) or col in(0,height-1) else ' ', end=' ')
    print()
print(width, 'x', height, sep='')
```

Output:

```
$ $ $ $ $ $ $ 
$           $ 
$           $ 
$           $ 
$ $ $ $ $ $ $ 
5 x 7
```

but I want to put the '5x7' inside the box like this:

```
$ $ $ $ $ $ $ 
$        5x7$ 
$           $ 
$           $ 
$ $ $ $ $ $ $
```

and for any other size the program runs
using python 3.5.2

Comment: Why? Also, the requirements are a little strange. For example, what if I type 3x3 - it won't fit in the box? What if I type 10x1 - there is no inside of the box?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this which uses the repeat string function that python has (i.e. "x"*3 is converted to "xxx").

```
while True:
  _char = str(input('Please enter a character: '))
  if len(_char)==1: break
  print("sorry, that's more than one character")
width = min(15,max(6,abs(int(input('Please enter a width between 6 and 15: ')))))
height = min(15,max(3,abs(int(input('Please enter a height between 3 and 15: ')))))

lng=len(str(width))+len(str(height))+1
print(_char*width)
print(_char + ' '*(width-lng-2) + "%ix%i"%(width,height)+ _char)
print((_char + ' '*(width-2) + _char +"\n")*(height-3),end="")
print(_char*width)
```

You'll have to limit the width of the box to 6 given that you could enter a two digit height where you now have an extra digit to worry about.  Alternatively you could check to see what the user enters will fit in the box before accepting his/her input - but that'll have to be implemented (ie a width of 5 will allow the text to fit in the box provided height is less than 10 - a condition that can easily be checked for).

Note that this uses python 3.5.  The end="" construct appended to the 2nd to last print ensures that print doesn't terminate with a carriage/line return.

It does work for everything I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
_char = input('Please enter a character: ')
width = int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
height = int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
for row in range(width):
    for col in range(height):
         if row in(0,width-1) or col in(0,height-1):
             print(_char, end=' ')
         elif row == 1 and col == 1:
             print(width, end = 'x')
         elif row == 1 and col == 2:
             print(height, end = ' ')
         else:
             print(' ', end=' ') 
    print()
print(width, 'x', height, sep='')
```

This prints in the box in the top left side. It can be easily changed to shift it to top right.

Comment: Doesn't work for `width` or `height` higher than 9, fails for width under `5` or height under `3`.